# 2 csv files returns different data types

Tags: r, csv

I have 2 csv data files. One in 1 minute bar and other with 5 minutes bar. 
Both of these files are in same format.

file 1 is

```
> 2007-01-02 10:00:00.000,NIFTY,ABB,2007-01-02 10:00:00.000,750.4,750.4,750,750.2
  2007-01-02 10:01:00.000,NIFTY,ABB,2007-01-02 10:01:00.000,750.38,750.4,749.8,749.8
  2007-01-02 10:02:00.000,NIFTY,ABB,2007-01-02 10:02:00.000,749.8,750,749.6,750
  2007-01-02 10:03:00.000,NIFTY,ABB,2007-01-02 10:03:00.000,749.6,752.4,749.6,752
  2007-01-02 10:04:00.000,NIFTY,ABB,2007-01-02 10:04:00.000,752,755.8,752,754.2
  2007-01-02 10:05:00.000,NIFTY,ABB,2007-01-02 10:05:00.000,754.02,755,752.05,753.6
  2007-01-02 10:06:00.000,NIFTY,ABB,2007-01-02 10:06:00.000,753,753,751,751
  2007-01-02 10:07:00.000,NIFTY,ABB,2007-01-02 10:07:00.000,751,751.62,750.5,751
  2007-01-02 10:08:00.000,NIFTY,ABB,2007-01-02 10:08:00.000,750.8,751,750.2,750.62
```

file 2 is

```
 > 2007-01-02 10:00:00.000,NIFTY,ABB,2007-01-02 10:00:00.000,750.2,754.2,749.8,753.6
   2007-01-02 10:05:00.000,NIFTY,ABB,2007-01-02 10:05:00.000,753.6,753.6,750.62,752.8
   2007-01-02 10:10:00.000,NIFTY,ABB,2007-01-02 10:10:00.000,752.8,752.8,750.2,751.5
   2007-01-02 10:15:00.000,NIFTY,ABB,2007-01-02 10:15:00.000,751.5,752,751,751.6
   2007-01-02 10:20:00.000,NIFTY,ABB,2007-01-02 10:20:00.000,751.6,751.6,750.8,751
   2007-01-02 10:25:00.000,NIFTY,ABB,2007-01-02 10:25:00.000,751,751.2,749,749
   2007-01-02 10:30:00.000,NIFTY,ABB,2007-01-02 10:30:00.000,749,751.8,749,751.8
   2007-01-02 10:35:00.000,NIFTY,ABB,2007-01-02 10:35:00.000,751.8,752,751.1,751.4
```

Now I run the 
a <- read.csv("file1.csv")

class(a[,1:4]) is factor

class(a[,5:8]) is numeric

while in case of file 2

b <- read.csv("file2.csv")

class(b[,1:4]) is factor

class(b[,5:8]) is factor.

How come class of columns 5:8 are factors. This factor type data not letting me go ahead with my analysis. Any idea.

Comment: Does the problem happen with that data alone, or are there additional rows?  Maybe there's a row in the second file that contains strings?  I believe that R would then coerce everything in the row to a string, and it converts strings to factors by default.  (See the `stringsAsFactors` parameter to `read.table`.)

Answer (score 4):

Hard to say without looking at actual files. There could be some characters hidden in those columns.

To find out, use `stringsAsFactors = F` in the `read.csv` to read factors as characters. Next, convert the character columns into numeric using `as.numeric`. This will introduce NAs in place of actual characters. Finally find out using `is.na`

Note: a factor type can be converted to numeric using `as.numeric`, but gives undesired result in this case.

Answer (score 2):

When I pasted your example data into two files and read both of these files in using `read.csv()`, both had the first four columns as factors and the second group of four columns as numeric, so I couldn't replicate your problem, unfortunately. It may be something in the files that didn't make it into your example.

When I modified "file2.csv" to read:

```
2007-01-02 10:00:00.000,NIFTY,ABB,2007-01-02 10:00:00.000,750.2,754.2,749.8,753.6
2007-01-02 10:05:00.000,NIFTY,ABB,2007-01-02 10:05:00.000,753.6,753.6,750.62,752.8
2007-01-02 10:10:00.000,NIFTY,ABB,2007-01-02 10:10:00.000,752.8,752.8,750.2,751.5
2007-01-02 10:15:00.000,NIFTY,ABB,2007-01-02 10:15:00.000,751.5,752,751,751.6
2007-01-02 10:20:00.000,NIFTY,ABB,2007-01-02 10:20:00.000,751.6,751.6,750.8,751
2007-01-02 10:25:00.000,NIFTY,ABB,2007-01-02 10:25:00.000,751,751.2,749,749
2007-01-02 10:30:00.000,NIFTY,ABB,2007-01-02 10:30:00.000,749,751.8,749,751.8
2007-01-02 10:35:00.000,NIFTY,ABB,2007-01-02 10:35:00.000,a,b,c,d
```

... I did indeed find that the last four columns were read in as factors, so that suggests to me that there may be non-numeric data somewhere in those columns of your "file2.csv".

I'd also note that you'd probably want to use something like:

```
a<-read.csv("file1.csv",header=F)
b<-read.csv("file2.csv",header=F)
```

... to avoid the first row being converted into headings but, whether I had `header=F` or not didn't change the outcome. FYI I'm using R 2.15.3 on Windows 7, 64-bit.

Comment: Thanks For your help. it did sort my problem. My file actually had NULL in one cell. When I removed NULL it works. Thanks once again

Comment: @user1177819: Glad to help. Please choose which answer helped you most and check the box to accept it. If you're not sure which one to choose, e4e5f4's answer was a little before mine and he or she identified the same potential problem, so you might want to choose that one.